# How to return the array points from a polygon?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

So here's my issue, which i'm sure a lot have ran in to.  I have a JSON file with an array of states and a sub array of lat and lng values corresponding to that state.

I loop through the states, then loop through the points then build the 50 polygons.

I now need to center and zoom on the state when it is clicked.  I realized I could loop though the points again, and add bounds.  However when I display the polygon in the console, I can click down through the values and see the points.

I assume there's a way to simply access these points without relooping through them... the points are already associated with a polygon, which is associated with a state.

When I try `console.log(newpoly.latLngs);`  I'm returned:

```
Kf

->b: Array[1]

->0: Kf

->b: Array[5]

->0: Q
     Xa: 41.0037
     Ya: -104.05560000000003
     __proto__: Q
  1: Q
     Xa: 44.9949
     Ya: -104.0584
     __proto__: Q
  2: Q
     Xa: 44.9998
     Ya: -111.0539
     __proto__: Q
  3: Q
     Xa: 40.9986
     Ya: -111.04570000000001
     __proto__: Q
  4: Q
     Xa: 41.0006
     Ya: -104.05560000000003
```

Sorry, i'm not sure how to make this look any cleaner.

Anyways I'd like to access the last array of the latLng points.  Or should I just add another loop for the bounds?

Thanks

Comment: Judging by the names of the properties ("Xa", "Ya" etc.), you shouldn't try and access them via `.latLngs` _property_ but instead look for something like `.getLatLngs()` (method). The property names may come from javascript minification, and may change completely with a new release (even minor one).

Comment: that's a very good point.  Thanks for saving me a headach down the line

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to get the bounding box for the polygons in an image map (I presume that is what you are using).

There is no need to write another loop; use the loop you have already written to calculate the boundaries and build the polygons simultaneously.

Comment: yeah, this is what I've started to do.  Just seems redundant to me, but i suppose it's done this way in api-3 to keep things smaller.  What are the best suggestions to prevent the bounds from being assigned as the last state in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

got it working in this way:

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://www.betafoot.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/states.json", function(json) 
{
var j = [];
var i = [];
var $length = Object.keys(json).length;
for (var j=1; j<$length+1; j++)
{
var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( );
var pts = [];
for (var i=0; i<json[j].points.length; i++) 
{
var id = json[j].stateid;
pts[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(json[j].points[i][1], json[j].points[i][2]);
latlngbounds.extend(pts[i]);
};
var newpoly = new google.maps.Polygon({
paths: pts,
strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",
strokeOpacity: 0.8,
strokeWeight: 2,
fillColor: "#FF0000",
fillOpacity: 0
});
newpoly.setMap(map);
newpoly.latlngbounds = latlngbounds;
newpoly.objInfo = id;
listenMarker(newpoly);
};
});
function listenMarker(newpoly)
{
google.maps.event.addListener(newpoly, 'click', function(event)
{
map.fitBounds(newpoly.latlngbounds);
});
};
```

as you can see i'm attaching the latlngbounds to the "newpoly", then accessing them from a separate function which handles the click action.  If anyone thinks this is a bad idea, please let me know.